# HTTP2 with gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, http2

Is it possible to run a Django Application using Gunicorn and HTTP2? Currently we have Nginx in front of our application working as a reverse proxy, but we may drop it in the future, since we are starting to migrate to docker swarm.

I could not find any docs/links regarding configuration of gunicorn with HTTP2. Does anybody knows if it is possible to do it, without using nginx?

If not possible, please suggest other webservers that can achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

gunicorn doesn't currently support HTTP/2. There's a [tracking issue](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1195) for it.

You can still use nginx with docker swarm. If you want to dynamically update the configuration, you can use something like [docker-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

If you want an alternative for use with docker swarm, I can recommend [traefik](https://traefik.io/). Although I haven't tried it with HTTP/2, it is meant to work.